# Can the label tags for attribute be associated with a normal div?

Tags: html, label, specifications

is it valid html under html5 definitions to use a label's "for" value as an id of a normal div element  (for example I have made a custom dropdown list implementation which is encased inside a div)

Please let me know if possible,

Thomas

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Not according to the spec:

> Some elements, not all of them form-associated, are categorized as
>   labelable elements. These are elements that can be associated with a
>   label element.
>
> "button" "input" (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state) "keygen"
>   "meter" "output" "progress" "select" "textarea"

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-label

See also:

> The for attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with
>   which the caption is to be associated. If the attribute is specified,
>   the attribute's value must be the ID of a labelable element in the
>   same Document as the label element. If the attribute is specified and
>   there is an element in the Document whose ID is equal to the value of
>   the for attribute, and the first such element is a labelable element,
>   then that element is the label element's labeled control.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-label-element.html#attr-label-for

I do think the question presents a valid use case. I'm not sure what the recommended pattern is for such a scenario, though ARIA attributes might help to make the markup more accessible:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Accessibility/ARIA/forms/Basic_form_hints 
https://developer.mozilla.org/Special:Tags?tag=ARIA

Comment: To expand, from the HTML5 spec: [The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/label.html#label)

Answer (score 3):

As Tim noted it is not possible to do it natively, however with a little bit of javascript you can simulate it

```
jQuery(document).delegate('[for]','click',function(e){
    var targetEl = jQuery('#'+jQuery(this).attr('for'));
    if(targetEl.is('div.your-custom-dropdown-class')) { //if targetEl is one of your dropdowns
        e.preventDefault();
        targetEl.trigger('click'); //open the drop down
    }
});
```