# Label For a Static DIV that shows entered value from a form

Tags: html, accessibility, section508

I have a Confirmation screen where previously-entered Form `input` fields are shown as static DIVs.

[image]

The HTML is below. The DIVs, though static, are focusable with TAB, allowing the user to hit them with the keyboard.

```
            <div>
                <label className="itemText"> <!-- Does this need a FOR ID? -->
                    First Name
                </label>
                <div id="divFirstName" tabIndex={0}>
                    {firstName}
                </div>
            </div>
```

In this case, is it necessary (or possible) to provide `label for=..` or `aria-label` to associate displayed `<div>` values with `<label>`s for 508 compliance, similar to what would be done for actual `input` controls? What should be done in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is have a "confirmation" type page to show the user what they entered into a form, you can use plain text and perhaps a heading before each value.

```
<h3>First Name</h3>
<p>Fred</p>

<h3>Middle Initial</h3>
<p>M</p>

<h3>Last Name</h3>
<p>Rogers</p>
```

[image]

All text on the page, unless intentionally hidden from assistive technology (eg [`aria-hidden="true"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-hidden)) is available to the user.  A screen reader user can use the <kbd>down arrow</kbd> key to walk all the elements in the DOM (that aren't hidden) so they can hear the text. And if you use semantic HTML such as headings (<h3>), the screen reader can quickly jump to a heading using either the <kbd>H</kbd> or <kbd>3</kbd> shortcut key. (Some screen readers have different ways to navigate to headings.)

To have a more pleasant user experience, for both the sighted user and screen reader user, using a table with row headers would be helpful.  Something like:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">First Name</th>
    <td>Fred</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Middle Initial</th>
    <td>M</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Last Name</th>
    <td>Rogers</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Your original question asked about making the confirmation values tabbable. They don't to be tabbable because screen reader users can navigate to the values as explained above so `tabindex` isn't needed.  However, if do want them to be tabbable, you can present the form to the user that looks similar to the original form by using an <input> with the [`readonly`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-readonly-attribute) attribute. That will allow the user to <kbd>TAB</kbd> to the input and they can copy the value but they can't change the value.

Also, since it's an <input>, you can use a <label> with the `for` attribute.

```
<label for="fname">First Name</label>
<input readonly value="Fred" id="fname">
<label for="mi">Middle Initial</label>
<input readonly value="M" id="mi" >
<label for="lname">Last Name</label>
<input readonly value="Rogers" id="lname">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[LABEL TAG - W3SCHOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

W3 says the "for" - attribute is only valid for FORM-Elements.

A workaround would be to just use FORM-Elements.

Or use the "role" - attribute:
[Accessibility Role, Name & Value](https://www.w3schools.com/accessibility/accessibility_role_name_value.php)

I think this might do the trick.

Comment: I hesitate to use `role="button"` or `role="link"` since these aren't interactive elements, so I would be distorting the truth.

Comment: "aria-label is intended for use on interactive elements, or elements made to be interactive via other ARIA declarations, when there is no appropriate text visible in the DOM that could be referenced as a label" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label

Comment: I was thinking because the element is interactive in that way, that it focuses on "TAB", maybe my definition of interactive was not right. I'll think of another solution...I have found something interesting, maybe using labels wouldn't be that bad considering this Post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76384561/10648655

Comment: But in that case it would be wrong to use a for-attribute that's correct.

Here they say aria-attributes should be used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11705966/10648655

Comment: And what I see here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-label_to_provide_labels_for_objects it'd be fit for your use-case...The only other thing that you could do is using a figcaption, as I understood this would be valid, possibly the best-practise approach in this case https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element

Answer (score 0):

I went with `role="region"` and `aria-label="label"`:

```
<div role="region" aria-label="This form is being completed by" tabIndex={0}>
```

Comment: That will be extremely confusing for a screen reader user or even a sighted keyboard user. What's the purpose of being able to TAB to a <div>?  You should only be able to TAB to interactive elements.  A better solution would be to use <input readonly>. That allows you to TAB to the element and the screen reader will read the value. You can also use <label for="id"> with the <input>.

Comment: Where was this answer when I was working on the code a few days ago :)

Comment: Do you want me to post this as a separate answer so that you can except it?

Comment: yes please.....